# Spring boot 2 with apache camel application start error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-8, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have a requirement where I need to listen to a active mq and call rest post api for the data I have recieved as body, for this I have created simple spring boot 2.x application and trying to start a router, but application is failing to start.

My understanding about registering a Router is to anottate a class with @Component and it should implement camel RouteBuilder

```
@Component
public class Router extends RouteBuilder{
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("timer:foo").to("log:bar");
    }
}
```

- JDK 1.8
- Spring boot version 2.2.6.RELEASE
- Camel version 2.24.0

  **Pom xml**

> ```
> <dependencies>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
>           <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
>           <version>${camel.version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
>           <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
>           <version>2.24.0</version>
>       </dependency>
>   </dependencies>
> ```

**The error I am getting is**

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.spring.spi.XmlCamelContextConfigurer
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `camel-spring` dependency. This should be pulled transitively through `camel-spring-boot-starter`.

The error message could be a problem with different Camel versions. For example if `${camel.version}` in your POM is not defined or not equal to `2.24.0` you could have mixed Camel versions for `camel-spring` and `camel-core`.

Answer (score 0):

If there will be any resource can't able to downloaded in your system so for this you have to uninstall the application and delete all the files from c/program-file/ and then install it again. Hope it will help you out from this issue.